# Is there a way to generate a barcode or a QR code from ObjectId in MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb

I am working on a project which needs to assign a barcode or a QR code to plenty of items. Is there a way to generate this starting from the `_id` field of the object?

Like for example:

- User adds an item
- Item gets generated with its `_id`
- A string coding a barcode or a QR is generated from the `_id`

Comment: qq. Though _id is unique? Is there any business reason you want to add/relate "_id" with QR/barcode? why can't be QR code generated independently and mapped with __id?

Comment: Yes, that's actually better. `_id` is a unique string of pseudo-random characters, so I thought it would be easy to turn into a barcode somehow, but I still don't know how to generate a barcode when creating a new document

Comment: use a Change Stream to get any created documents and feed the _id into whatever you use to create QR codes. Then update the doc with the QR code.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. For Change Stream you mean an event listener?

Answer (score 0):

you can use jsbarcode library for generating barcodes

Answer (score 0):

MongoDB Object Ids are twelve byte hexadecimal values. The maximum value a barcode can hold id of 1556 bytes. Hence you should have no problem converting them into barcodes.

First, convert the hex value to decimal. Then Generate a barcode with the corresponding decimal value.

On the client where you are reading the barcode, convert the decimal back to a hex value.

Comment: Thanks! What about a QR code, does it work any differently?

Comment: Nope, it's the same, you can select either depending on your purpose. Let's just say you're using it for a receipt a qr is more intuitive because your customer can scan it with their mobile. Let's just say you have a hardware barcode scanner you might go with a barcode. A mobile qr scanner can scan both barcodes and qr nevertheless.